# Angular : using a service to conditionnally import modules

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-scope

i have i service which i use to load a list of module :

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  public allowedModules: any = this.modulesFilter();

  constructor() {
  }

  public modulesFilter() {
    const testPef = true;
    const modulesList= [];
    if (testPef === true) {
      modulesList.push(MyFirstModule);
    } else {
      modulesList.push(MySecondModule);
    }
    return modulesList;
  }
}
```

then in my module file , i want to use it like this :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MyService.allowedModules  // THIS IS WRONG
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    MyService
  ],
  exports: [
  ]
})
export class MyModule { }
```

**Of course it's wrong as i need to not access directly to my service**

**Suggestions?**

Comment: I can't even think of a legitimate reason to do this. Can you give some reasoning/background info behind what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to conditionnaly import my modules : i can use testPef  value from a web service that i can call

Comment: How will the Angular compiler know how to create the bundle that your `MyModule` module falls in? The bundles are made at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: If you can explain your exact requirement it will be easier to give an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you achieve that using lazyLoading

```
 export class LoadGuard implements CanLoad {
  constructor(private myService : MyService , private router: Router) {
 }
 canLoad(route: Route): boolean {

  if (this.myService.canBeLoaded()) {
       return true; 
 } else {
    return false;
 }  
} 


{
  path: 'test',
  loadChildren: 'app/test/test.module#TestModule',
  canLoad: [LoadGuard]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`canLoad`](https://angular.io/guide/router#canload-guard-guarding-unauthorized-loading-of-feature-modules) guard along with [LazyLoading](https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration). Your service can be called from `canLoad`